# Show that the number of $a$ such that $n$ passes Miller's test to the base $a$ is $\le 22uv$

Tags: number-theory

Let $u$ and $v$ be odd numbers such that $p=8u+1, q=16v+1$ are primes.

Let $n=pq$.

Show that the number of $a$ such that $n$ passes Miller's test to the base $a$ is $\le 22uv$

I know that i can list all the congruences satisfied by $a$ and find the solution, but i have no idea how to prove this inequality.

Answer (score 5):

Write $n - 1 = pq - 1 = 2^3 (16 uv + u + 2v)$ and let $m = 16 uv + u + 2v$.

Note that $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$ is equivalent to $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$.

By considering primitive root, we can see that the number of $a$ satisfying $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ is $\gcd(m, p - 1) = \gcd(m, 8u) = \gcd(m, u)$ and that of $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$ is $\gcd(m, q - 1) = \gcd(m, 16v) = \gcd(m, v)$. Hence the number of solutions to $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$ is $\gcd(m, u) \gcd(m, v)$.

Similarly, for a fixed $0 \le k \le 2$, the number of $a$ satisfying $a^{2^k m} \equiv -1 \pmod{pq}$ is at most $\gcd(2^k m, 8u) \gcd(2^k m, 16v) = 2^{2k} \gcd(m, u) \gcd(m, v)$.

Summing up, we have $$\gcd(m, u) \gcd(m, v) + \sum \limits_{k = 0}^{2} 2^{2k} \gcd(m, u) \gcd(m, v) \\= 22 \gcd(m, u) \gcd(m, v) \le 22 uv $$

as desired.